# Failed to update “Operating System Updates”

Tags: ubuntu

all! I've got the elementaryos 6 Beta running on my Lenovo Flex and got an error message while trying to update, starting a few days ago:

Failed to update “Operating System Updates”

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  pantheon-online-accounts-plugin-lastfm: Depends: switchboard-plug-online-accounts (= 2.0.1+r925+pkg63~daily~ubuntu6.1) but 3.0.0+r46+pkg65~daily~ubuntu6.1 is to be installed
  pantheon-online-accounts-plugin-fastmail: Depends: switchboard-plug-online-accounts (= 2.0.1+r925+pkg63~daily~ubuntu6.1) but 3.0.0+r46+pkg65~daily~ubuntu6.1 is to be installed
  pantheon-online-accounts-plugin-mail: Depends: switchboard-plug-online-accounts (= 2.0.1+r925+pkg63~daily~ubuntu6.1) but 3.0.0+r46+pkg65~daily~ubuntu6.1 is to be installed
```

Not certain if this is a problem with something I've done or what - any help would be appreciated! Should I just apt get install the 3.0.0+r46+pkg65~daily~ubuntu6.1 package and see if that fixes it?

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt full-upgrade`.
Full-upgrade performs the function of upgrade but may also remove installed packages if that is required in order to resolve a package conflict. Check and accept this answer if this works for you. Make a comment if this does not work.